# How can I change the opacity of everything but the element I'm hovering over in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have people highlight over a laptop image and once they do so, I want everything but the laptop image I'm hovering over to ease into a black opacity color.

This is the code I have so far which makes everything in the body to change opacity:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".laptop_img").mouseenter(function() {
        console.log("Mouse over laptop");
        $("body").css("opacity", "0.5");
    });

    $(".laptop_img").mouseleave(function() {
        console.log("Mouse leaves laptop");
        $("body").css("opacity", "1");
    });
});
```

Comment: And your relevant HTML?

Comment: Fiddles are always great too.

Comment: You best bet is to not try to animate the opacity of each DOM element, but rather insert a z-indexed layer that you can move your highlighted element in front of and then change the opacity of that layer to hide everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier way to achieve this would be to create a fixed black semi-transparent element that is the size of the window, on top of everything, make it hidden by default and show it whenever the mouse hovers `laptop_img`.

You would also have to handle the hovered element's z-index so that it would appear on top of your black element.

Demo on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edc642pz/2/

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` CSS property applies to all the children of the element so if you do it on `body` then you `img` tag will have `opacity:0.5` too.

So better solution could be add/show dynamically a `div` witch will be covering all body except the your image.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get what You want:

1/ You need to have these two compontents in separate container. For example

```
<div id="div-with-opacity" style="opacity:.7">
      everything what goes here will has opacity also
   </div>
   <img src="path-to-image" alt="" id="this-image-has-no-opacity"/>
```

2/ Just use `rgba(0,0,0,.7)` color as a background of layer. You can have elements inside div with this background and it's not affect these elements.